# MassTransit Hosted Service Saga Statemachine timeout on Http POST

Tags: masstransit

Hello getting this error when submitting a model through my ProductHttpAggregator service controller:

Exception thrown: 'MassTransit.RequestTimeoutException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
MassTransit.RequestTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for response, RequestId: 00040000-ac13-0242-e33f-08d9ac27912
at MassTransit.Clients.ResponseHandlerConnectHandle`1.GetTask()
at ProductHttpAggregator.Controllers.OrderController.Post(OrderViewModel model) in C:\Users\tom.fanara\source\repos\SlideXTestSaga\ProductHttpAggregator\Controllers\OrderController.cs:line 57 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)

> Here is the JSON request body

```
{
"Id" : "35e12ba0-feb2-42ed-bdd5-322fc507d5f2",
"Timestamp" : "10/15/2021",
"CustomerNumber" : "45678",
"PaymentCardNumber" : "9101112",
"Notes" : "test3"
}
```

Here is the code section in the controller. Both my MassTransit and service are connected to RabbitMQ.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Post(OrderViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(ModelState);

        var (accepted, rejected) = await _submitOrderRequestClient.GetResponse<OrderSubmissionAccepted, OrderSubmissionRejected>(new
        {
            OrderId = model.Id,
            InVar.Timestamp,
            model.CustomerNumber,
            model.PaymentCardNumber,
            model.Notes
        });

        if (accepted.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
        {
            var response = await accepted;

            return Accepted(response);
        }
```

> here is the hosted service setup

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddMassTransit(x =>
                {
                    x.AddDelayedMessageScheduler();

                    x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();

                    // By default, sagas are in-memory, but should be changed to a durable
                    // saga repository.
                    x.SetInMemorySagaRepositoryProvider();

                    x.AddSagaStateMachine(typeof(OrderStateMachine), typeof(OrderStateMachineDefinition));
                    
                    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
                    {
                        if (IsRunningInContainer)
                            cfg.Host("rabbitmq", h =>
                            {
                                h.Username("guest");
                                h.Password("guest");
                            });

                    cfg.UseDelayedMessageScheduler();

                        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                    });
                });

               
                services.AddMassTransitHostedService(true); 

            }).ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
            {
                logging.AddSerilog(dispose: true);
                logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            });

    
}
```

> here is the publisher startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHealthChecks();

    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();

    services.ConfigureTelemetryModule<DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule>((module, o) =>
    {
        module.IncludeDiagnosticSourceActivities.Add("MassTransit");
    });

    services.TryAddSingleton(KebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter.Instance);
    services.AddMassTransit(mt =>
    {
        mt.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
        {
            cfg.Host(IsRunningInContainer ? "rabbitmq" : "localhost", "/", h =>
                {
                    h.Username("guest");
                    h.Password("guest");
                });
            
            MessageDataDefaults.ExtraTimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
            MessageDataDefaults.Threshold = 2000;
            MessageDataDefaults.AlwaysWriteToRepository = false;

            cfg.UseMessageData(new MongoDbMessageDataRepository(IsRunningInContainer ? "mongodb://mongo" : "mongodb://mongodb:27017", "attachments"));
        });

        mt.AddRequestClient<SubmitOrder>(new Uri($"queue:{KebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter.Instance.Consumer<SubmitOrderConsumer>()}"));

        mt.AddRequestClient<CheckOrder>();
    });

    services.Configure<HealthCheckPublisherOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
        options.Predicate = check => check.Tags.Contains("ready");
    });

    services.AddMassTransitHostedService();

    services.AddOpenApiDocument(cfg => cfg.PostProcess = d => d.Info.Title = "Sample API Site");

    services.AddControllers();
}




enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't getting a response, it might be that you didn't start the bus. When configuring MassTransit, you should have:

```cs
services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
```

Right after the `AddMassTransit(...)` configuration.

Comment: Thanks Chris I added my configurations to the code above. Both the hosted service/statemachine and publisher have the services.AddMassTransitHostedService(); and my output shows the bus as started. However sometimes I get a connection failure still. Usually the GET in the controller works but there seems like some latency in getting all the RabbitMQ connections and channels to start.

Comment: Loaded 'SlideX.Core.EventsGreenPipes.DynamicInternal722bb49c205348b995e871e4c57a9dfe'. 
info: MassTransit[0]
      Bus started: rabbitmq://rabbitmq/
MassTransit: Information: Bus started: rabbitmq://rabbitmq/

Comment: you can add `AutoStart = true` to the bus configuration to ensure the response endpoint is setup.

Comment: Hi all my fault I did not add the consumers in my hosted service! Now it posts fine and my connections>Channels>Exchanges are all working! Very cool!

Thanks Chris!

Comment: In further versions `services.AddMassTransitHostedService();` is obsolete;